# Does the ES6 Method Definition Shorthand only create one function object?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

With the "old way" of creating classes in JavaScript, you mostly avoid doing something like this:

```
function Car {
    this.make = "Renault";
    this.model = "Twingo";
    this.name = function () {
        return this.make + this.model;
    };
}
```

because it would create a new function object at each instantiation of the class, so you'd rather do this:

```
function Car {
    this.make = "Renault";
    this.model = "Twingo";
}

Car.prototype.name = function() {
    return this.make + this.model;
}
```

In ES6, and with the newer `class` syntax we can do something like:

```
class Car {
    constructor(make, model) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
    }
    name () {
        return this.make + this.model;
    }
}
```

Does this only create one shared function object? Or does it instance a new one at each `new` call like the first one?

Comment: “In ES6 we have this syntax to define a method:” No, that doesn’t look valid. But the `class` snippet after that only creates one function and puts it on the prototype, yes. (You can check with `'name' in Car.prototype`.)

Comment: That syntax is valid in object literals (which is obviously one function per object since there is only one object) and in classes (which is one function on the prototype, no matter how many objects are created). It is not valid in a function like you showed.

Comment: @Ry- look at the MDN doc I linked, I took it from there. Perhaps I applied it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you applied it wrong.

Comment: The link is showing it in an object literal, not a function. `const car = { make: "Renault", model: "Twingo", name ( ) { return this.make + this.model } };` is valid, but it creates a single object, not a class or constructor function. `name ( ) { return this.make + this.model }` on it's own is not valid outside of a class definition or object literal.

Comment: I guess the `class` version is valid though? And does it create a single function object like @Ry- says, or one for instance like @Randy Casburn says?

Comment: Ry is correct about it. It creates a function on `Car.prototype`, which will be shared by Car instances. This is easy to check. `const car1 = new Car; const car2 = new Car; console.log( car1.name === car2.name );`

Comment: I don't think that would create a function object for each instance. You can try transpiling this to older JavaScript and check what it does. ES6 does mostly the same thing, only internally.

Comment: @OndraŽižka: It’s already JavaScript…

Answer (score 2):

Functions that you define as a property inside constructor will be created for each instance. Functions that you define outside constructor will be available on ths prototype. So the name functon will be created only once.

Say this is your class

```
class Test {
  constructor(prop1, prop2) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;
    this.func1 = function() {};
  }
  func2() {}
}
```

const test = new Test('one','two');

If you check in devtools you can see func1 is available for each instance but func2 is available for on the prototype.

```
Test {prop1: "one", prop2: "two", func1: ƒ}
  func1: ƒ ()
  prop1: "one"
  prop2: "two"
  __proto__:
    constructor: class Test
    func2: ƒ func2()
```

Comment: Please, replace the screenshots with the pasted code. This is a really important practice on StackOverflow in order to improve searchability.